# What exactly is Unicode codepage 1200?

Tags: unicode, codepages

While investigating some localization options, I stumbled across this as a save option in Visual Studio.

What is Unicode code page 1200 exactly?

The Microsoft documentation page [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) describes:

> Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications

So is Unicode code page 1200 really UTF-16 and therefore has a BOM?

Is it advisable to use this for JavaScript then, and if we have to use this, is a `charset` declaration necessary in the script tag?

Comment: If the codepage specifies the byte order as the documentation you quote shows then a BOM is not supposed to be used. In other words, UTF-16 little endian is not permitted to have a BOM, according to the Unicode standard. See Table 2-4: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch02.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I thought that BOM is attached for UTF 16, but finally got it cleared up now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Code page 1200 is UTF-16 little endian, and does not imply BOM or not.
For anything web use UTF-8 (everything: css, html, javascript, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Use UTF-8 for JavaScript, don't bother with UTF-16 or any of its variants (for JavaScript; this advice doesn't apply generally).

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation about the [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers), code page 1200 means the following:

> Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications

Likewise 1201 is the same, but with big endian byte order.

> Unicode UTF-16, big endian byte order; available only to managed applications

Comment: That's just a duplicate of the question though... doesn't give any meaningful answer